# How to fetch and merge data of the same collection with different URL?

Tags: backbone.js

I have an API that gives me paginated results, like:

http://quickstart.local/api/conversations/326/messages?page=1

so `url` is a function that changes each time I want to fetch another page.

When I fetch a new page, my collection resets and only the new results will be kept inside the `collection`. If I fetch with the same URL, the merge is done though. Is there a way to avoid this? I've already tried to fetch like this:

```
this.fetch({
    reset : false,
    merge:true,
    add: true,
    success : opts.success,
    error : opts.error
});
```

but it does not work at all. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've forgotten the `remove: false` option. Fetch exploits the `collection.set` method, which takes the parameters [listed here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set)